# Is it possible to flag Settlement placements as personal?

Tags: fallout-4

Basically, I don't want all these randoms I barely tolerate living in my hometown to sleep in MY bed.  I want to set my bed (and my house, for that matter) as mine and tell the unfortunates I rescued to stay out of it.  It doesn't seem like much to ask in exchange for saving them from raiders/deathclaws/mediocrity.  Is there a way to do so?

While I appreciate any answer, I should note that I'm trying to protect the house the main character lived in during the prologue, so tricks involving unusual bed locations aren't likely to work for me.  I'm still interesting in hearing them, though, so don't let that dissuade you from answering!

Comment: This should be renamed to 'How do I get those filthy settlers to stay off my lawn?'

Comment: Do settlers still show up if you don't build a radio tower? That might be a possible solution, but it's probably not that easy.

Comment: @twobugs The first five from the main quest always move into Sanctuary, which is where the main character's house is.

Comment: I didn't realize this was specifically about that house, my bad. I think my idea would work in a general sense, though. I'm curious to see what people can come up with for Sanctuary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try assigning Danse or Strong (assuming you have one of them) to the bed you want. Those two, maybe some others, don't sleep so you can keep their bed as your own as they never use it. You can use it as normal.

Comment: This is an ingenious move, and so I will also move (the checkmark, to your answer).

Answer (score 26):

Try setting up a bed on the second floor, deconstructing the stairs, and building a neighboring, unattached structure (or just a plain wooden staircase) that you can scale and use to jump over to your luxurious second floor bedroom.
[image]

Sorry Dogmeat, not THIS time. Find your own bed.
[image]

Comment: That is a creative, unexpected solution, +1.  Unfortunately, it won't work for me, because the bed I'm trying to protect is in my son's room.  I'll add that to the question (I didn't think it would matter!).

Comment: Nice fix. Are there perhaps other, more convenient/conventional ways you can do area access control? Like, lockable or computer-controlled doors?

Comment: You could cut off ground access to the second floor entirely and place a the teleport-mat on that floor, so whenever you come back to town, you're already in a place no NPC can get to. This also helps during attacks, so you can scout out the situation. Make sure to leave some power armor up there too. ;)

Nothing else besides those that others have mentioned; either assign beds to NPCs, or keep NPCs out entirely. If there's a secret way to wire a door up to the grid and lock it, I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 11):

I've read that you can assign settlers to beds, so if you stay on top of which settlers you've assigned to which beds, you should be able to keep the people you've lovingly helped out of your bed.

Comment: I'm curious to hear from someone who's actually tried this. That's a lot of bed assigning at this point.

Comment: Every new settler seems to assign himself to that bed (I even tried scrapping it and building a new one, since I thought it might be that they were self-assigning to the oldest bed first, it didn't help), though.  Once the settlement maxes out, though, I think just reassigning one settler should be a solution - until someone dies.

Answer (score 7):

Seems like Settlers can't handle fences either.  Another easy option would likely be to simply put up a fence around your area with no gate.  You may have the occasional issue with someone spawning inside the fence, but I don't believe I've ever seen a settler spawn inside a house other than the one with the initial workbench.  You can jump the fence with ease, your settlers are stuck outside looking in longingly.  Just make sure not to put a gate in it, because they WILL use that.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InsurmountableWaistHeightFence

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution to this that I've found is to simply have a settlement without any settlers to serve as your own personal home base.

I've built out the Red Rocket station as a personal crafting, storage, and showcase area, and it's where I send my companions when I dismiss them. Meanwhile, I've built up Sanctuary as an actual settlement. Because the Red Rocket station is 'uninhabited', I have no issues with settlers taking my stuff or using my bed, and they are free to manage their own affairs in the village next door.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not. In fact, I have the distinct impression from the way Preston talks about Sanctuary that he doesn't really acknowledge that you were there first!

Comment: I haven't had any settlers move into the Red Rocket area because I haven't set up any beds. I think Sanctuary is unfortunately always going to have Preston and his gang, because they move there during that questline, but if you don't build amenities no one will come?

Comment: Scaring everybody away by making the place uninhabitable is different to designating an area as yours

Comment: Is placing a bed the only requirement for filthy settlers to show up and try to sleep in it? Get your own bed, Boston!

Comment: @kalina very true, although I'm unsure if scaring (by that definition) is functionally different from theoretically designating an area as mine